# angular bootstrap typeahead close select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I would like to get the select list to close when the form is submitted with a values which is not on the list (using typeahead-focus-first). I used the [typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) plunker example as a starting point.

When the user hits enter, the storeItem function fires, but the list does not close.

```html
<form ng-submit="storeItem()">
  <input type="text"
    typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
    typeahead-focus-first="false"/>
</form>
```

The submit function:

```js
$scope.storeItem = function() {
   $scope.selected = Date.now();
};
```

See full plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nsQXVAyjuB5WpIgE2rWZ?p=preview)

How do I go about closing the list, while keeping the input value and the list intact?

Comment: Do you see this problem following the exact plunkr link in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead? Do you have it inside the Demo page? Can you describe your steps precisely to get this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have found a bug.  The area of interest is in the typeahead directive - element.bind('keydown' method.  There is logic to not close the dropdown when enter or tab is pressed and nothing is selected:

```
// if there's nothing selected (i.e. focusFirst) and enter is hit, don't do anything
if (scope.activeIdx == -1 && (evt.which === 13 || evt.which === 9)) {
  return;
}
```

The input element loses focus and the popup does not close.  You should open an issue on the [repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues).

Comment: Thanks @rob-j, I've [done that](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3545). If they confirm it is an issue, I'll mark you answer as accepted.

Comment: Can you provide the link to that line on Github (you get it by clicking on the line number)? I couldn't find it in the latest version.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev [Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L285) to line.

Comment: I see. It might be intended - note similar behavior here https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete

Comment: The material version does not seem to exhibit the same behavior.  The problem being with the ng-bootstrap version, the input element loses focus and the dropdown remains open where the material version does not lose focus.